# Calculating $\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{d x_1}{2\pi}...\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{d x_N}{2\pi} (\sum_{j=1}^N e^{i x_j})^n (\sum_{k=1}^N e^{-i x_k})^n$

Tags: integration, combinatorics

I'm working on a problem about correlated random walks, and in trying to solve it, I've run across integrals of the following form for non-negative integers $N,n$:

$$I(N,n) = \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{d x_1}{2\pi}...\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{d x_N}{2\pi} \left(\sum_{j=1}^N e^{i x_j}\right)^n \left(\sum_{k=1}^N e^{-i x_k}\right)^n$$

These integrals appear to be degree $n$ polynomials in $N$ with integer coefficients, at least from the lowest few orders. In the following, I'll use the fact that $\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{d x}{2\pi} e^{i m x} = \delta_{m 0}$ for integer $m$.

For $n=0$, the integral is trivially $1$, so that $I(N, 0)= 1$.

For $n=1$, note that $\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{d x_1}{2\pi}...\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{d x_N}{2\pi} e^{i (x_i - x_j)} = \delta_{i j}$, so that $I(N,1)=N$.

For $n=2$, I have a little bit of a harder time. By considering cases of when pairs of indices are equal, I've convinced myself that $\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{d x_1}{2\pi}...\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{d x_N}{2\pi} e^{i (x_i + x_j - x_k - x_l)} = \delta_{ik}\delta_{jl}+\delta_{il}\delta_{jk} - \delta_{i j k l}$, so that $I(N,2) = 2N^2-N$.

As an aside, I'm curious if there might be a connection to combinatorics and counting arguments, given that the coefficients of the polynomials appear to be integers.

---

What is the explicit form for $I(N,n)$ as a degree-$n$ polynomial in $N$? This might be too tricky, so please note that I will also accept an answer that allows me to explicitly write the polynomials up to $n=50$, so that I can check some of the subleading asymptotics and check the coefficients on the OEIS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use the multinomial theorem (in [multi-index notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-index_notation)) to rewrite the powers of the sums. Then the integral becomes
$$ I(N,n) = \sum \limits_{\substack{\alpha \in \mathbb{N}_0^N \\ \lvert \alpha \rvert = n}} \binom{n}{\alpha} \sum \limits_{\substack{\beta \in \mathbb{N}_0^N \\ \lvert \beta \rvert = n}} \binom{n}{\beta} \int \limits_{[0,2\pi]^N} \frac{\mathrm{d} x}{(2\pi)^N} \, \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} (\alpha - \beta) \cdot x} \, . $$
From your observation it is clear that the individual integrals are equal to $\delta_{\alpha\beta}$, so
$$ I(N,n) = \sum \limits_{\substack{\alpha \in \mathbb{N}_0^N \\ \lvert \alpha \rvert = n}} \binom{n}{\alpha}^2 , $$
meaning that your integral is equal to the sum of the squares of the multinomial coefficients. It is discussed in these MO questions ([general case](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/128249/estimate-on-sum-of-squares-of-multinomial-coefficients), [small $N$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/407305/sum-of-squares-of-multinomial-coefficients)). While some asymptotics and expressions for the leading coefficients are derived, no closed formula seems to be known.

The evaluation for small values of $n$ is manageable though and confirms your results $I(N,0) = 1$, $I(N,1) = N$ and $I(N,2) = N \cdot 1 + \binom{N}{2} \cdot 4 = N (2 N - 1)$. Similarly, we find
$$ I(N,3) = N \cdot 1 + N (N-1) \cdot 9 + \binom{N}{3} \cdot 36 = N (6N^2 - 9 N + 4) \, . $$
In principle this can be continued up to $n = 50$, but there might not be a simple way.

Comment: Good use of the multinomial expansion, and I really like the regrouping into terms with fixed $m=\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{1}_{\alpha_i >0}$ to extract a factor of $\binom{N}{m}$. Here's an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8iQ8.png) showing some Mathematica code implementing this. I show the results from $n=1$ to $n=10$, and the code can get the polynomials up to about $n=20$ before getting a bit too slow. Not quite $50$, but I think it's enough for my purposes, and I feel you've answered my question as thoroughly as it gets.